# Undefined Symbols error when integrating Apptentive iOS SDK via Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, apptentive

When integrating the Apptentive iOS SDK via Cocoapods, I get the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ATConnect", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ATAppRatingFlow", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ATSurveys", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: 

error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How should these errors be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found that adding the Apptentive cocoa pod to an existing Xcode project may potentially not include some of our required frameworks.

Check your linker flags:

```
Target > Build Settings > Other Linker Flags
```

You should see `-lApptentiveConnect` listed as a linker flag:

```
... -ObjC -lApptentiveConnect ...
```

You should also see our required Frameworks listed:

- Accelerate
- CoreData
- CoreText
- CoreGraphics
- CoreTelephony
- Foundation
- QuartzCore
- StoreKit
- SystemConfiguration
- UIKit

  ```
  -ObjC -lApptentiveConnect -framework Accelerate -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreText -framework Foundation -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework CoreTelephony -framework StoreKit
  ```